# Extract data from PDF into Excel if possible in Python

Tags: python, pdf, data-extraction

I'm looking for advice how extract data from pdf files - into spreadsheet, [drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmQJd.png), each file is technical drawing with a lot of lines, numbers, sometimes small tables, I would like to extract information from bottom right corner, there is irrregular table, in each drawing table is in different order, dimension, number of columns and cells.

I tried tabula-py but tabula can't see any table there, I tried also Adobe PDF Services API and python script extracted some data to json, but it couldn't find any table.

I'm looking for advice how I can detect the table only in specyfic location (right bottom corner) and extract data into spreadsheet.

Thank you in advance

1 Update: I went to simple code:

```
import tabula 
import pandas as pd 
df = tabula.read_pdf('/testpool/2.pdf', pages = 'all') 
for i in range(len(df)): 
 df[i].to_excel('file_'+str(i)+'.xlsx')
```

Ended with error:
Cannot read JBIG2 image: jbig2-imageio is not installed
So, I used solution from [github.com/chezou/tabula-py/issues/166#issuecomment-609066708](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/issues/166#issuecomment-609066708)
Created new .jar via maven from cloned repro, new file is 1.0.6, when python needs 1.0.5 so simple replacement and changing name doesn't work. I'll keep you posted.